# 24V battery charger with LM723

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging, current-limiting

I have a 28V steady DC input, and I want to use it to charge 2x12V lead-acid batteries in series.

I want to use the **LM723 IC** to make an adjustable (26V to 28V) regulated output, as it has current limiting capabilities. So I used the Positive Switching Regulator figure from the datasheet with the recommended values for R1 and R2, but the circuit is not working neither in simulation nor reality.

[image: Circuit from the datasheet]
[image: Circuit with ISIS Proteus for simulation (**updated**)]

Am I missing something? I checked multiple times.

Is my choice for the transistors right? I can't find 2N5005 and 2N5153 locally.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: What is Vref set to? Is the Vout high or low?

Comment: @Aaron Vref is set to 7.15V, and Vout I believe is high

Comment: @jsotola You are right. I used UA723 datasheet, and the LM723 datasheet is different. I updated the schematics but still the same result. Post updated

Comment: the cap on the output may be required

Comment: To charge a 24 volt battery (or two 12 volt in series), you need to supply about 29 volts to the batteries, so your input voltage must be over 30 volts.

Comment: @PeterBennett Does not `Positive Switching Regulator` mean that the circuit is able to boost voltage also?

Comment: @jsotola no, the cap did not do any good

Comment: on P1, exchange the top connection with the wiper connection .... connect R4 and C1 to the wiper of P1 ... connect R1 to the top of P1

Comment: The 2N5087 is capable of 50mA only switch current. Output current <= switch current. You have a collector connection missing in the top diagram, wherever that came from. Buck converters do not boost voltage. It needs a decent load and output capacitor to oscillate- it's ye old-fashioned hysteretic converter. Not sure how well that "current limit" operates. Maybe it's more like short-circuit protection so beta limited. 1N4005 is a bad choice for a SMPS diode, it should be faster- UF4005, 1N5819 etc.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Battery charging is not just a matter of setting a voltage regulator at a magic voltage.  It's actually quite complicated to do without aging the battery prematurely.  You are better developing circuitry that supplies  a quality COTS charger what it needs.

Answer (score 1):

For fully charging a 24V lead-acid you need almost 29V, and this topology cannot supply it.

On the other hand, remember this IC has two main Vref connections, one for Vo<7V and one for Vo>7V. So I think you naeed to change the connections, and I agree with earlier comments the Potentiometer connections could be interchanged in order to vary what N.I.input compares. [image: For reference, I attach a 1973 diagram, intended for 5V output]

My last remmark, is you're using a legacy IC meant for linear application as a switcher.